# How to have 'adaptive' structure name?

Tags: swift

So I am creating a struct and putting the results into an array like so

```
struct roundResults {
    let round: Int
    let team1Total: Int
    let team2Total: Int
}

var allResults = [roundResults]()
```

Then I am filling the struct and appending it to the array like so

```
func createStruct(){
    let (result) = roundResults(round:RoundNumber , team1Total:team1GameTotal , team2Total:team2GameTotal)
    allResults.append(result)
}
```

And when I print the data from the array it gives me this

```
[Game.ScoreScreen.roundResults(round: 1, team1Total: 0, team2Total: 3), 
Game.ScoreScreen.roundResults(round: 2, team1Total: 0, team2Total: 10)]
```

---

What I want to achieve is that instead of the struct being labeled like

```
Game.ScoreScreen.roundResults
```

I get something where `roundResults` represents the current round

I created a new variable and tried to use this var in lieu of round results when created the structure but this doesn't seem to work

```
func createCall(){
    roundCall = "results" + String(RoundNumber)
}
```

What I would like to have is something like `let (result) = (roundCall)(round:RoundNumber...` so I have an easy way to pull each array depending on what round I am currently in and the printed data would look something like

```
[Game.ScoreScreen.results1(round: 1,
Game.ScoreScreen.results2(round: 2, etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

You're currently just using the default print behaviour of structs.

You can make your struct conform to the [`CustomStringConvertible][1] protocol by implementing the`description` property. This lets you specify how you would like your struct to be represented in a string format, such as for printing.

Here's an example:

```
struct roundResults: CustomStringConvertible {
    let round: Int
    let team1Total: Int
    let team2Total: Int

    var description: String {
        return "Round \(round) results: Team 1: \(team1Total) vs Team 2: \(team2Total)" // TODO: Adjust this to work as you wish.
    }
}
```

Now when you print your array, it'll show:

```
["Round 1 results: Team 1: 0 vs Team 2: 3", "Round 2 results: Team 1: 0 vs Team 2: 10"]
```

Comment: I don't want to just print the results though, sorry if this was unclear. I'd like to use the data if a user returns to a previous round to fill the information back into labels I have on screen. So either a way for custom array names to be created per array, or a way to call each array depending on `round` number inside the array.

Comment: Having different structs for each round wouldn't solve this. It seems like you're looking for a [`Dictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID113)